# How to go to an error using only the keyboard in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Let's say I have a file with 10 lines and I have a problem with the name of the package (or something) and the cursor is on the last line of the text.

How can I go directly to that line to see what the problem is and what suggestions there are to remove the problem, using a shortcut?

Question: Is there a keyboard-shortcut for this?

Or something like this:

*Go to the next error* and *Go to the previous error*.

Comment: see also Lars Vogel Tutorial: Navigation shortcuts in the editor http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseShortcuts/article.html#shortcuts_navigationeditor

Answer (score 337, accepted):

Windows and Linux

- Go to the next error: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>**.**</kbd>
- Go to the previous error: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>**,**</kbd>
- Show quick fixes: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

Mac

- Go to the next error: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>**.**</kbd>
- Go to the previous error: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>**,**</kbd>
- Show quick fixes: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

Comment: Cool, this is very useful! Unfortunately on the Mac, `Cmd-,` opens the preferences. But the shortcuts can be changed in Preferences -> Keys -> Next and Previous (I've just set them to `Cmd-.` and `Cmd--` for previous and next)

Comment: On Mac, try `Cmd-.` and `Cmd-Shift-.` for next and previous. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Is there a command to go to next error in *any* of the workspace project?

Comment: @ring0, poolie: we are discussing that at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329438/how-can-i-go-to-the-next-eclipse-marker-e-g-build-error-using-the-keyboard).  The short answer is "no", though there are a few helpful suggestions there.

Comment: Thanks! For me it jumps to warnings as well, though, (using Eclipse Juno), can I change this somehow?

Comment: Any way to have it skip warnings and only goto to real errors (that show red in side bar)?

Comment: A better alternative to Ctrl + 1 for quick fixes is the `F2` key, at least in Windows.

Comment: What is this command called in **Preferences... > General> Keys**?   I'm not seeing it show up in the list of conflicts when I try to assign another command the Ctrl + . hotkey when Editing in Structured Editor

Comment: Ok, apparently what here we are calling "next error" and "previous error" commands, are just the keyboard shortcuts for the generic Next and Previous commands.  These keys probably go to the next and previous of something else in contexts where there is no concept of errors.

Comment: Note, cmd/ctrl + . only works for errors in the file you have open at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately it also jumps to warnings for me. Any way to change that (only jump to real errors)?

Comment: Note, you can see the error message, which usually shows up in the mouse-over popup, in the status bar at the bottom.

Comment: Is there any command to show the error message using keyboard which usually shows up in the mouse hover

Answer (score 42):

To go to problem within project just type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> then press <kbd>X</kbd>. It will open the "Problems" window. Now use <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> to select the error/warning and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to it.

I know it isn't simple as <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> but it works for a whole project.

Comment: As a side note, and to complete answer using `CTRL+.`.

To only show errors, you can configure the problems problems visibility level to skip warnings and only show errors.

Answer (score 10):

To complete the previous answers, you can use the combobox linked to the toolbar buttons for next/previous annotation to set the annotation level.

[image: toolbar-combobox]

That makes browsing through errors using ctrl+./ ctrl+ easier,

Comment: OMG I'm crying of joy this feature exists (filtering the annotation)!
I wanted it years ago, now I'm again developing with Eclipse and I've found this feature thanks to your answer! Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

TO GO TO NEXT ERROR ONLY in eclipse with `Ctrl + .` command, tick off warnings as shown in screenshot

[image]