# How can I go to the next Eclipse marker (e.g. build error) using the keyboard?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Suppose I make a method signature change that breaks several callers, and I want to review the call sites manually to update them.

Once I change the signature, my "Problems" view shows, say, a dozen errors.

What keys can I hit to navigate through them while leaving the keyboard focus in the editor for fast fixups?

(It's been a while, but I think the Visual Studio equivalent is <kbd>F8</kbd>.)

Note that this question does not duplicate [Eclipse: How to go to a error using only the keyboard (keyboard-shortcut)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832183/eclipse-how-to-go-to-a-error-using-only-the-keyboard-keyboard-shortcut), as that one seeks to navigate only between markers in the current file.  In this case, I want to go to the next error regardless of which file it's in.

("Marker" is the general Eclipse term for errors, warnings, etc.)

Answer (score 24):

The best I've come up with so far is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to flip to the Problems view, then <kbd>↓</kbd> to pick the topmost error, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to it (which returns focus to the editor).

Answer (score 10):

Here's a way to move to the next error, regardless of editor, in one keystroke.  It's not perfect, but it works until it's fixed in Eclipse.

1. Open a "Markers" view.  Click the down arrow at the top right, and choose "Configure Contents".  Uncheck the show all box, and create the view to show only the problems you want to see.  You'll probably want to deselect "warnings" and "errors" as well.  Save it.
2. Click the same "Markers" down arrow, and choose "Group By".  Select "None".  This is important because you don't want the parent tree level nodes to show, otherwise some of your "next" actions will take you to those, which don't represent an error.
3. In Eclipse -> preferences -> keys, search for "Markers".  If there is not a keystroke bound to the Markers view, create one.  I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
4. Get a keyboard hotkey tool like AutoHotKey (for PC's) or iKey for the Mac.   I'm using iKey, but there are plenty of other Mac tools you can use.  In your hotkey tool, define an action for the keystroke you want to use for "next error".  I chose the standard <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
5. For that keystroke/action in your hotkey tool, generate 3 keystrokes in the following order:

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>
   - <kbd>Down arrow</kbd>
   - <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Of course, you'll want to change the first one to whatever you picked for yours.  You'll probably want to restrict that action to be executed only when Eclipse is the current application.
7. Save that, create some compile errors, and test it.

Answer (score 9):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> for Quick access popup window.

If the "Markers view" is not already visible, then type in "markers", in the searchbox on the popup window. Once you have selected it, it should stay available, when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> the next time around.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, after refactoring some parts of code. I had a lot of errors in different files and i had to go through all of those.
I used the following solution:

1. Mark all (relevant) entries in the Problems view.
   To do this switch to the Problems view using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and select the entries with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>
   You can also select all entries using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Open the marked errors by pressing <kbd>↵</kbd>.
   Every file containing at least one marked error will be opened.
   The cursor will automatically select one error/file, as if you open only this specific entry
3. Fix the errors in the opened file.
   Here you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to navigate to next error inside this file
4. Close the file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> when your done.
5. Eclipse will automatically focus the next file and you can go back to step **3**

In my case this solution was much faster then switching to the Problems view each time.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328460) entered for this that has an attachment that looks like it does what you want.

Comment: That bug seems to be about navigating between search results.  I haven't actually tried it yet, so I don't know whether it works for markers as well.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You contribution doesn't actually answer the question though. :-)

Comment: Upvoted, knowing underlying issues allows us to track and vote for them at the source. Especially in this case when there really isn't a good, native answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could use AutoHotkey:
save the mouse position, send a mouse event to click on the arrow in CDT console and then return the mouse back to it's original location. Record the mouse coords with window spy or use autohotkey's search by image function (first capture the images of two arrows with printscreen into bitmaps).