# Eclipse: How to go to a file which has errors by shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I read [Eclipse: How to go to a error using only the keyboard (keyboard-shortcut)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832183/eclipse-how-to-go-to-a-error-using-only-the-keyboard-keyboard-shortcut), but I want to go to another file which has errors. Can I do it by shortcut?

Comment: This question appears to duplicate [How can I go to the next Eclipse marker (e.g. build error) using the keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329438/how-can-i-go-to-the-next-eclipse-marker-e-g-build-error-using-the-keyboard).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like [bug 13300](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13300): Next/Previous error for all Java elements [browsing] [package explorer], from 2002(!):

> It would be cool if Next/Previous Error would work for all Java elements i.e. would open/reveal the editor if the file is not in the active editor.

... and no, right now this feature hasn't been implemented yet.