# Eclipse shortcut for "Next error" (Ctrl-.) not working

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I see in several published lists of Eclipse shortcuts that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> is supposed to take me to the next error (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to the previous one).

However, those combinations do nothing in my environment. I am running Eclipse Luna in Windows 8.1.

In `Preferences->Key`, I see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> is bound to an action named `Next`, not `Next error`. I don't see a `Next error` anywhere. I unbound it and assigned a new key combination to it, just in case, to no avail.

Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> work only for errors in current editor window.

There is a discussion and some suggestions for finding the next error in the whole project here:

[How can I go to the next Eclipse marker (e.g. build error) using the keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329438/how-can-i-go-to-the-next-eclipse-marker-e-g-build-error-using-the-keyboard?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there are two bindings for the keys.

Go to Preferences -> Keys.
In the "type filter text" field type in "Ctrl+."  (not the keys, but the letters)

If there are more than one than the one not named "Next" - it will be overriding it.  You can safely select the other one (not the "Next" one) and "Unbind Command"

The PDT plugin always seems to add one that I have to delete.