# Can eclipse show compilation error text more automatically?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to make eclipse show the text of a compilation error when you are simply located with the caret on the line with errors? switching to the mouse and hovering the small red X icon to the left (or the row) is so tedious....

Answer (score 1):

You could go through errors [with the designated key-bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832183/eclipse-how-to-go-to-a-error-using-only-the-keyboard-keyboard-shortcut), and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to show the available quick fixes. That's my fastest known version.