# Eclipse keyboard shortcut for error

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to view below error without having to hover over my mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Moving the cursor to some red-underlined text, in my Eclipse the error message is then also shown in the status bar (bottom-left of the window). It's not always exactly the same text as is given in the mouse-over-popup, but usually close enough to figure out what's wrong.
Going to the error with Cmd/Ctrl+. should place the cursor at the right spot to show the error message in the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Linux

```
Go to the next error: Ctrl + .
Go to the previous error: Ctrl + ,
Show quick fixes: Ctrl + 1
Mac

Go to the next error: Cmd + .
Go to the previous error: Cmd + ,
Show quick fixes: Cmd + 1
```

[Found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832183/eclipse-how-to-go-to-a-error-using-only-the-keyboard-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: I have already read that, it's not exactly same as what suggests you get when you hover your mouse ot that bulb or cross. It shows quick fixes while bulb shows suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to the next error: Ctrl + .
Go to the previous error: Ctrl + ,
Show quick fixes: Ctrl + 1
Show suggestions and quick fixes: F2
```

So <kbd>F2</kbd> servers the purpose of bubble which shows suggestions and on clicking quick fixes for multiple error on the same line. With <kbd>F2</kbd> one just have to propagate through each error.